What is the bare minimum host SW for running docker
Note here that I'm not meaning the SW in the docker image itself. To be clear the docker image itself could be arbitrary, say let's put a full-blown Ubuntu therein with desktop environment all inclusive. The example maybe a bit contrieved, but the aim is to have no limitations on the containers themselves. In reality I'm striving to put various servers in containers, but I wouldn't want to have a such a minimilistic that I put constraints on what I could put in the containers (in the future).
The system to host such a thing is what I'm looking for. Would a suitable initramfs be enough?

That depends on the use case. The only person who can determine that for certain is yourself. The best way to find out is to try it yourself until you have what you want. It is an image so you can just keep at it and delete and start until you find out.

@NasirRiley However a usecase is mentioned in the question. Note that your proposal seems to imply that an initramfs image is enough to start with (which would mean that I have to create such an image myself because I'm pretty sure that the one distros come with doesn't contain docker). Otherwise I don't have an image that I can remove stuff from and reboot and see if it (still) works.

I never gave the faintest suggestion that an initramfs image or anything is enough or not enough. I stated that it not known. There is no indication of what will be done with the Ubuntu desktop or anything else and even that is going to depend as any suggestions may not like up with what you will see. That is why the best way to do it is to try it on your own so that you know for sure what is needed.

"Boot-to-container" is the concept you describe in your example. It's been tested. (though I'll argue that docker won't be the container orchestration of choice there, for a desktop system).
There's multiple "slimmed down" (I won't say "minimized", even if software people love that term, unless you can mathematically prove it's the smallest possible) Linux distros doing exactly that. Take Fedora CoreOS as an example, which is optimized to boot on cloud / virtualized environments and quickly launch containers / container orchestrators (say, kubernetes).
Yes, you could set up such a system to run completely from an initramfs; question is whether that is very helpful if you later need to load a complete Ubuntu.
Also not that putting your full Ubuntu into a single container kind of misses all the advantages of containers (decoupling dependencies, elegant replacing of services, limited cross-service file system visibility, decoupling user management…) and incurs nearly all the complexity downsides. If you want to use containers for the easy "roll-back-ability", then you'd probably be looking for image-layering-based OSes, like Fedora Silverblue. Or is it about the dependency management? Some people really like NixOS for that; I'm not fully convinced, but maybe it's for you!
If you really only have a container that you want to boot, bootc might be your choice, but I wonder why one 1. take effort to put a complete desktop Linux into a container as far as possible (it's not completely possible, because, well, hardware! Runtime control! Shutdown! All things that live outside your container), then 2. add the things that you moved out of the container back into the container, then 3. boot that container.
